# Get row and column value of a cell which has a note in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I need to get row and column number of a cell which has a note in the spreadsheet.There is a method to get all comments or notes in the spreadsheet, but I want to get row and column index of that cell instead of its note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

range.getNotes() returns a 2 dimensional array for the range specified.  assuming the range is getDataRange() then search the array for the note you are interested in

```
    var notes = sheet.getDataRange().getNotes();
    for( var i=0; i<notes.length; i++ ) {
      for( var j=0; j<notes[0].length; j++ ) {
        if( notes[i][j] === note ) {
          Logger.log("row = "+(i+1)+" col = "+(j+1));
          return;
        }
      }
    }
```